# Can someone show me how to display time + additional minutes in Objective C

Tags: datetime, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Say the hour is 15:03.
Say variable minutesToAdd is 39

What's the code that will display 15:42 on a UILabel (current time + minutesToAdd)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code, I dont check it in XCode (and its will not compiled just after copy/paste), but the idea is like I wrote below:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dc = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];

dc.minute = 39;

NSDate *srcDate = NSDate(15:03);   // Create date here

NSDate *resultDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dc toDate:srcDate]; // Here is your new date
```